# setText() in Android TextView does nothing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android xml layout file like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#184A64">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#F1CF2F"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descLogoTop"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logoTop" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoBot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#F1CF2F"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descLogoBot"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logoBot" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/logoTop"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="date"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="103dip"
        android:layout_height="62dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="#F1CF2F"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Its a simple layout with two ImageViews on top and bottom of the screen and a LinearLayout in the middle. What I want is to get some data from a Bundle and write it in the LinearLayout. For this I have the following Java code:

```
public class NewsD extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null; 
    private Runnable viewNews;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private News m_news = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_activity);

        bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

        m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NewsD.this,    
                this.getString(R.string.wait), this.getString(R.string.receiving, true));

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                getNews();
            }
        });                                 
    }

    public void getNews() {

        m_news = new News();
        m_news.setNewsTitle(bundle.getString("title"));
        m_news.setNewsText(bundle.getString("text"));
        m_news.setNewsDate(bundle.getString("data"));
        m_news.setNewsPhoto(bundle.getString("photo"));

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_activity, null);

        try{
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

            if (iv != null) {
                try{
                    Bitmap bmp = Utils.getBitmapFromURL("http://www.myserver.com/IMG/" + m_news.getNewsPhoto());
                    if (bmp == null){
                        Log.i("PHOTO ERROR", "http://www.myserver.com/IMG/" + m_news.getNewsPhoto());
                    }
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);                     
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("IMAGE ERROR", e.getMessage() + " - " + e.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(m_news.getNewsTitle());
            }
            if(bt != null){
                bt.setText(m_news.getNewsText());
            }   
            TextView dt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.data);         
            Date nd = new Date(Long.parseLong(m_news.getNewsDate())*1000);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(nd);
            dt.setText(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }

        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the 3 TextViews and the ImageView show the default text/image, specified in the xml. I have checked

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
```

statements and seem to work fine. They are not null. Also, data coming from the bundle is fine. I've made like 1 hour of research on this, and changed the code to add the runOnUiThread() statement to make sure the getNews() function is ran in the UI thread. But nothing works. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the problem is that you are inflating the view in the getNews call into memory, but that view is not displayed.  The view will already be inflated once you call setContentView.  So, instead, use the view like this:

```
public void getNews() {

    m_news = new News();
    m_news.setNewsTitle(bundle.getString("title"));
    m_news.setNewsText(bundle.getString("text"));
    m_news.setNewsDate(bundle.getString("data"));
    m_news.setNewsPhoto(bundle.getString("photo"));



    try{
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you are getting NetworkOnMainThreadException, but since you are catching exception you are losing the data as to what exception you are getting. RunOnuiThread is not the right way in your case.

Use an Asynctask and move all UI code e.g layoutinflation, setText, setImageBitmap to either OnPreExecute or OnPostExecute and move below line to doInbackground of Asynctask.

```
Bitmap bmp = Utils.getBitmapFromURL("http://www.myserver.com/IMG/" + m_news.getNewsPhoto());
```

Comment: Although he will get that error as well if running on Jelly Bean.